# How to add new string between a string python

Tags: python, string

I have a string 'A,B' which is separated by `,` or `and`

The String could have several words like 'A,B,C'. It may be 3 or 4 words and more.

Now I need to replace `,` with `or`. Any `and` should not be replaced.

Give an example string 'A,B,C and D' . My expected result is `A or B or C and D`

My attempt:

```py
str1 = 'A,B,C and D' 
str1.replace(',', ' or ')
```

Is this the correct method?

Comment: So, where do you want to add new string?

Comment: @dyy.alex into a new variable

Comment: So assign to a new variable? What is the exact issue there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `replace()` method replaces the `old` (old string) in the string with `new` (new string). If the third parameter max is specified, the replacement will not exceed max times.

```py
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```

And more, if you do not need to replace `and` just delete `.replace('and','and')`.

```py
str1 = 'A,B,C and D' 
str1 = str1.replace(',',' or ').replace('and','and')
print(str1)
```

`replace()` method need a `=` operator.